# How to get the date as in required format: ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I want to declare the date in the below code in the format of `(yyyy mm dd hh mm ss)`.

```
postData(data) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    var pingData = {
        date: new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
    }
}
```

When I declare it as shown in the above a code, I'm getting the error as

> Cannot find name 'year'. Cannot find name 'month'.....

I want the `date` variable to be `string` type. So, how can I get the date as I mentioned in the above format?

Answer (score 2):

Try This Maybe Helpfull for you

**in AppModulePage**

```
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';

providers: [DatePipe]
```

**in demo.component.ts**

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
.
.
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

ngOnInit() {
   var date = new Date();
   console.log(this.datePipe.transform(date,"yyyy mm dd hh mm ss")); 
}
```

Comment: what about the time?

Comment: ngOnInit() {
   var date = new Date();
   console.log(this.datePipe.transform(date,"yyyy mm dd hh:mm:ss")); 
}

Answer (score 1):

use this format it will work  `var d = new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 33, 30, 0);`

Comment: here are you declaring the date & time statically?

Comment: I mean this is the format you should follow.  you can pass it the way @Praveen Kumar Tripathi used it.

Comment: this.datePipe.transform(date,"yyyy mm dd hh:mm:ss") this format is dynamic working and hh:mm:ss is also shown Hours:Mins:Sec